# capture the environment of ellipsis/dots

Tags: r, metaprogramming, ellipsis

{rlang} has this unexported function that can be used to capture the ellipsis arguments (names, expressions, and env). It powers the magic of `rlang::enquos()`.

```r
f <- function(...) rlang:::captureDots()

g <- function(...) f(..., b = z)

g(a = x, y)
#> $a
#> $a$expr
#> x
#> 
#> $a$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$expr
#> y
#> 
#> [[2]]$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$expr
#> z
#> 
#> $b$env
#> <environment: 0x130f8d8a8>
```

I would like to isolate, and hopefully understand this functionality but I don't find my way in the C code, there's a lot of it in rlang and it seems touching anything breaks everything.

My request is to have a minimal, efficient, self contained way of recreating this functionality (with or without inspiration from {rlang}).

Capturing the names and expressions is easy enough in base R, but fetching environments is not. I don't believe this can be done without low level languages.

---

Here are tougher examples :

```r
n <- 1
fun1 <- function(x, ..., y) {
  n <- 2
  fun2(n, ..., j=x, u = y, v = n)
}

fun2 <- function(u, ..., v) {
  n <- 3
  rlang:::captureDots()
}

res <- fun1(1, i=n, x = n, y = n)
res
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$expr
#> n
#> 
#> [[1]]$env
#> <environment: 0x11232d778>
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$expr
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> $i
#> $i$expr
#> n
#> 
#> $i$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> $j
#> $j$expr
#> x
#> 
#> $j$env
#> <environment: 0x11232d778>

lapply(res, function(x) eval(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $j
#> [1] 1
```

```
dots <- (function(...) get("..."))(1, i=n, x = n, y = n)
res2 <- with(list(... = dots), fun1(...))
lapply(res2, function(x) eval(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $j
#> [1] 1
```

```
foo <- function(...) {
  bar <- function() rlang:::captureDots()
  bar()
}

foo(a=x)
#> $a
#> $a$expr
#> x
#> 
#> $a$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

foo2 <- function(...) {
  bar <- function(...) rlang:::captureDots()
  bar()
}

foo2(a=x)
#> NULL
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `capturedots` function in `capture.c` in the source for rlang?

Comment: Actually, `rlang_capturedots` is where it seems to capture the environment, with the environment being the `CAR` of the `args` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I could trace captureDots ->  ffi_capturedots -> rlang_capturedots (and r_node_cdr) -> capturedots and most of the logic seems to be there. my plan was to clone the repo and trim it down until I got the basic functionality left but that didn't work well

Comment: When you say that everything breaks, do you mean that the functionality breaks, or that you can't compile it anymore?

Comment: I can't compile

Comment: pryr::where finds the environment of a name without using C.

Comment: It looks recursively for a binding, here there are no bindings

Comment: If you don't mind I'll remove the `rcpp` tag as this isn't about `Rcpp` (though it is a neat question).

Comment: We're missing a tag for those r questions that most likely require C or C++ though... I had the tag C too but somebody removed it as well, probably for similar reasons. A distinct expertise should have its distinct tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although it's possible to write a function that can iterate down the call stack in R, collecting calls and environments along the way (see the addendum below), the code is very complex, and there are too many gotchas, such as calls made via `eval`, to make it a robust solution one could use in production code. Rather than trying to recreate the contents of the dots from the call stack, it is better to extract and evaluate the contents of the `...` object directly.

Unfortunately, this does require a small amount of compiled code. Under the hood, in the C code, a `<...>` object is stored as a `DOTSXP`, which is a specialized pairlist of *promises*.  Each promise contains an unevaluated expression and the environment in which the expression should be evaluated. There are no user-facing functions in base R that allow direct extraction of environments and expressions from promises; they need to be obtained using the C functions `PRENV` and `PREXPR`, which are accessible from Rinternals.h. We can access the full pairlist of promises inside a `DOTSXP` using the C functions `TAG`, `CAR` and `CDR`, which are also accessible in Rinternals.h.

This means that in total we need 5 trivial C functions:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('SEXP cdr(SEXP obj)    { return CDR(obj);   }')
Rcpp::cppFunction('SEXP car(SEXP obj)    { return CAR(obj);   }')
Rcpp::cppFunction('SEXP tag(SEXP obj)    { return TAG(obj);   }')
Rcpp::cppFunction('SEXP prenv(SEXP obj)  { return PRENV(obj); }')
Rcpp::cppFunction('SEXP prexpr(SEXP obj) { return PREXPR(obj);}')
```

Although I have used Rcpp for convenience here, these functions could be written in a C file in your package, making this solution dependency free.

With these functions now defined, we can emulate `rlang:::captureDots` with the following function that uses only base R and the above C functions:

```r
capture_dots <- function() {
  
  dots <- tryCatch(
    get("...", parent.frame()),
    error = function(e) list()
  )
  
  if(identical(dots, list())) return(list())
  
  li <- c(car(dots), cdr(dots))
  first_name <- deparse(tag(dots))
  if(first_name != 'NULL') names(li)[1] <- first_name
  
  lapply(li, function(x) {
    x <- list(x)
    while(inherits(x[[1]], 'promise')) {
      env <- prenv(x[[1]]) 
      x   <- list(prexpr(x[[1]]))
    }
    if(is.null(env)) env <- .GlobalEnv
    list(expr = x[[1]], env = env)
  })
}
```

*(Note: Thanks to the OP for making several very useful suggestions for developing and improving this function via the comments)*

Now if we run the given examples, we have:

**Example 1**

```r
n <- 1
fun1 <- function(x, ..., y) {
  n <- 2
  fun2(n, ..., j=x, u = y, v = n)
}

fun2 <- function(u, ..., v) {
  n <- 3
  capture_dots()
}

res <- fun1(1, i=n, x = n, y = n)
```

Resulting in

```r
res
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$expr
#> n
#> 
#> [[1]]$env
#> <environment: 0x0000022784b38020>
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$expr
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> $i
#> $i$expr
#> n
#> 
#> $i$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#> 
#> 
#> $j
#> $j$expr
#> x
#> 
#> $j$env
#> <environment: 0x0000022784b38020>
```

and

```r
lapply(res, function(x) eval(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $j
#> [1] 1
```

**Example 2**

```r
dots <- (function(...) get("..."))(1, i=n, x = n, y = n)
res2 <- with(list(... = dots), fun1(...))
lapply(res2, function(x) eval(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $j
#> [1] 1
```

**Example 3**

```r
foo <- function(...) {
  bar <- function() capture_dots()
  bar()
}

foo(a=x)
#> $a
#> $a$expr
#> x
#> 
#> $a$env
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>


foo2 <- function(...) {
  bar <- function(...) capture_dots()
  bar()
}

foo2(a=x)
#> list()
```

---

**Addendum**

To do the whole thing in R would involve walking the call stack, grabbing arguments and environments as you go. This works well for the majority of use cases but won't work when there are `eval` calls on the stack such as `with`, as in the second example. This is included to show how something similar can be done in base R. It could be developed further to handle calls to `eval` etc, but is already much more complex than the above solution.

```r
capture_dots2 <- function() {
  
    dots <- tryCatch(
    get("...", parent.frame()),
    error = function(e) list()
  )
  
  if(identical(dots, list())) return(list())
  
  ss <- lapply(sys.status(), function(x) rev(head(x, -2L)))
  ss$sys.frames <- c(ss$sys.frames[-1], parent.env(tail(ss$sys.frames, 1)[[1]]))
  stack <- list(call_stack  = ss$sys.calls, call_frames = ss$sys.frames)
  stack$call_stack <- lapply(stack$call_stack, function(x) as.call(as.list(x)))
  
  get_args <- function(x) as.list(x)[nzchar(names(as.list(x)))]
  funcs <- rev(lapply(seq_along(stack$call_stack), sys.function))
  stack$frml <- lapply(funcs, get_args)
  stack$args <- lapply(stack$call_stack, function(x) as.list(x)[-1])
  dots <- Map(function(args, frmls) {
    if(!'...' %in% names(frmls) || is.null(names(frmls))) return(NULL)
    args <- args[!sapply(args, function(x) identical(x, quote(...)))]
    if(length(frmls) == 1) return(args)
    if(is.null(names(args))) names(args) <- rep("", length(args))
    matched_frmls   <- which(names(frmls) %in% names(args))
    matched_args    <- which(names(args) %in% names(frmls))
    if(length(matched_args))  args  <- args[seq_along(args)[-matched_args]]
    if(length(matched_frmls)) frmls <- frmls[seq_along(frmls)[-matched_frmls]]
    dot_frml <- which(names(frmls) == "...")
    pre_dot <- if(dot_frml == 1) numeric() else seq(dot_frml - 1)
    unnamed_args <- which(!nzchar(names(args)))
    if(length(unnamed_args) > length(pre_dot) && length(pre_dot) > 0) {
      args <- args[-unnamed_args[pre_dot]]
    }
    args
  }, stack$args, stack$frml)
  
  envs <- stack$call_frames[lengths(dots) > 0]
  dots <- dots[lengths(dots) > 0]
  result <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(dots)) {
    for(j in rev(seq_along(dots[[i]]))) {
      li <- list(expr = dots[[i]][[j]], env = envs[[i]])
      if(identical(li$expr, quote(...))) next
      nm <- names(dots[[i]])[j]
      nms <- names(result)
      result <- c(list(li), result)
      names(result) <- c(nm, nms)
    }
  }
  rev(result)[order(names(rev(result)))]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll award the bounty in the end so it gathers more exposure. Is there a reason why you're looking twice and nesting the promise in a list in the second loop ?

Comment: @moodymudskipper the promise gets evaluated early if it is assigned directly rather than being wrapped in a list, so this is necessary. However, you're right about the double loop. Better to do this all in a single `lapply`. That even gets rid of the need for the final `Map` call.

Comment: A few comments that might not make much difference (I don't need them addressed) : I noticed that we can't use `get0()`, probably because of a bug. The tryCatch() might be avoided however by feeding the dots to the function and using missing (I'm assuming tryCatch() to be slow but I don't really know). We might test if first_name is null before deparsing and spare nanosecs. I also think type of() is faster than inherits(). We're lucky to have you Allan. Thanks so much for the great work and enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @moodymudskipper thank you. And thanks for a great question that made me learn a bit more about R.